# Using Bayesian formula to apply uncertainty to topic probability given length of document

Tags: probability, bayesian, prior, uncertainty

After computing topics ($z$) over a word network, I'm assigning topic probability to documents, following:

$$p(z|d) = \sum_{w_i}p(z|w_i)p(w_i|d)$$

with $d$ being a document composed by $w_{i...n}$ words.

With this setting, I have that very short documents get a high probability of belonging to a certain topic $z$, because $p(w_i|d)$ is very high. Eg. if a document (after removing stop words, adverbs etc) has only 4 words, all belonging with high probability to topic $z$, also $p(z|d)$ will be very high. Furthermore, in truth, my $p(w_i|d)$ are scaled using word scores (TfIdf and more), so it's very easy that one word get very high relative document probability.

I would like instead to add some uncertainty given by the fact that with shorter documents is harder to define a topic. I could do it with various weighting schema, but I prefer to use something theoretically sound, using a weakly informative prior.

I'm no Bayesian expert, how should I behave?

- I guess my likelihood probability is a Beta distribution, how do I encode document length?
- Which is a conjugate prior (I would like to avoid mcmc, given the processing time).
- should I parametrize the prior around the topic mean probability or around zero?